# add code on every latex beamer frame

Tags: beamer

I would like to add some lines of code at the beginning of each frame, like the code which is uncommented here. However, the `addtobeamertemplate` does not work in the way I expected it. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
\documentclass[slidestop]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{frame begin}{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2pt}}{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2pt}{0pt}}
\addtobeamertemplate{frame begin}{\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt}}{\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt}{0pt}}
\addtobeamertemplate{frame begin}{\vspace*{-10pt}}{\vspace*{-10pt}}

\begin{frame}{Test}
%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2pt}
%\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt}
%\vspace*{-10pt}

\begin{block}{Test}
\end{block}
\begin{gather*}
a=b
\end{gather*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, `frame begin` is used only when `beamer` is in `article` mode.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the hint, so I search for a corresponding replacement for normal mode. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you want to achieve. This would make it easier to think of alternate ways.

Comment: I want that the three lines of code `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt}
\vspace*{-10pt}` are added automatically after the `\begin{frame}` command on every frame. For blocks this works as shown here with `\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}` but for a frame it does not work this way. Is it clearer now what I want to achieve?

Comment: @7asd44 Yes but why do you what it at the beginning of a frame? You could simply set it globally and done with it... BTW using an `@<name>`in your comment will alert the `<name>` user of a new comment.

Comment: It's really not clear what the 'bigger picture' is here.